# Bash - Sorting an Array

Tags: arrays, bash

Here is my simple code:

```
#!/bin/bash

arr=(3 5 1 2 0 9 8 2)
for i in ${arr[@]}; do printf "%s /n" "$arr[@]" done | sort -n
```

I am receiving the following error:

```
syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I have a 'for' loop, which I ended with 'done'. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems here.

The syntax error is caused by the missing `;` before the `done`.
Another syntax error on the same line is the `"$arr[@]"` instead of `"${arr[@]}"`.

```
for i in ${arr[@]}; do printf "%s /n" "${arr[@]}"; done | sort -n
```

Now this is correct syntax, but I don't think it does what you expect.

To print a newline after each number, you need to write `\n` in the `printf` instead of `/n`.

To print the content of the array sorted, you can write:

```
printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}" | sort -n
```

Or write with a loop:

```
for v in ${arr[@]}; do echo $v; done | sort -n
```

But using both techniques together doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Works perfectly well! Thank you sir :)